# How to put the characters that have a matching group in bold?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a tab header with alphabet character: a b c d e f g h i j k l ..Z
That how I initialize this in my code: I have declared an array:

```
char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
```

then for each alphabet letter carac I call the following function by the doing:

```
foreach (char carac in alpha)
        {
            writer.Write(generateTabheader(carac));
        }
```

And the function is:

```
private string generateTabheader(char currentChar)
        {
            string tabHeaderHTML="<li id=\"tabHeader_" + currentChar.ToString() + "\" style=\"float:left;color:blue; margin-right:10px;margin-left:10px\">" + currentChar.ToString() + "</li>";
            return tabHeaderHTML;
        }
```

so it displays a tabheader with all aphabet letters, and when the user select a character he will get back all the groups starting with this character. I succeeded to get back all the groups using a caml query and i stored the result in this list: result = list.GetItems(query). How can I put the characters of my tab header that have a matching group in my result list ( by matching I mean a group title starting with this character) in bold and the others in italic?

Answer (score 0):

Use a click handler to detect the event. Assign a classname to all the li's like class="example"

```
    $('.example').on('click', function(event){
       $('.example').each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('.thisClassmakesitalic');
       }
       $(this).addClass('thisClassmakesitalic');
    });
```

and now add a CSS style to make the element or its parent or anything italic.

Comment: Thank you for your aswer. Why would we use a click handler? I actually want the user while he will be accessing the page to see the alphabet letters displayed in the top of the page and have in bold letters the letters that have a matching group ( a group in the list starting with this letter) and those who don't they will be in italic, the user will not have to click on the letter to see this it should be displayed like this from the beggining when he well be accessing the page. I'm sorry if I did not get your idea, I'm starting with coding in c# and javascript .

Comment: @sara can you post an example of your code in a jsfiddle so I can exactly understand what you are trying to do visually. I thought you were just creating a list of tabs with characters and you want to change the style of those tabs after clicking.